# Flutter: check if a list contains only a certain value

Tags: list, flutter, dart, if-statement

I need to know if there are only string  equals to "Validated" in the list, how can I check it in 1 line of code ?
(If the list is empty, I already checked the condition before so this particular case isn't important).

```
List<String> state_str_list = ["Validated", "Draft", "Draft", "Waiting", "Validated"];
if (???) {
    print("all values in state_str_list are equals to 'Validated' !");
}
```

Comment: check `List.every` method - the docs say: *"Checks whether every element of this iterable satisfies test.

Checks every element in iteration order, and returns false if any of them make test return false, otherwise returns true."*

Comment: use `list.contains` method like `state_str_list.contains("value");`

Comment: `List<String> state_str_list = ["Validated", "Draft", "Draft", "Waiting", "Validated"].where((element) => element.contains("Validated")).toList();`

Comment: @lava he wants a `true` / `false` boolean, not a list - this is where `List.every` should be used, not `List.where`

Comment: `var d = ["Validated", "Draft", "Draft", "Waiting", "Validated"]
    .contains("Validated");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to you, I came to this:

```
contains_only(var _list, var e) {
  _list.every((element) => element == e);
}
print(contains_only(["Validated", "Draft", "Draft", "Waiting", "Validated"], "Validated"));
```

Comment: or more simple: `_list.every((element) => element == e);`